# Creating Multiple Independent Toggle buttons for card descriptions

Tags: angular

I want to create a toggle button on every card that shows its own description.

i know that i can bind different variables with buttons but that's not a solution for me because i may have many cards and its uncertain. please help me with the problem.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="card" *ngFor="let atl of TodayAttendance">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                <td><button (click)="expandDetails()"></button></td>
                          <td>{{ atl.employee.name }}</td>
                          <td style="color:teal">{{ atl.punchIn }}</td>
                          <td style="color:tomato">{{ atl.punchOut}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p>Hello</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**TS**

```
   expandStatus=true;
      expandDetails(){
        if(this.expandStatus==true){
         this.expandStatus=false;
        }
    else{
         this.expandStatus=true;
        }
      }
```

Comment: If each card can be expanded or collapsed, then each card (i.e. each element of the TodayAttendance array) must have an `expanded` flag. You can't possibly use a single boolean field in your component to contain the state of all the cards. If you do, then either all the cards are expanded, or all the cards are collapsed.

Comment: you can pass the item in expandDetails function so you can track its status `(click)= expandDetails(atl)` and the atl item can store `atl.expandStatus: boolean`

Answer (score 1):

- **Create** a new specific component to encapsulate the card's logic, let's say `today-attendance-card.component`
- **Move** the boolean `expandStatus` inside it's typescript code, making them all independant. Also **move** your `*ngFor="let ..."`  one `<div>` above
- **Add** an `@input() alt: any;` to the top of your new component ts code to give your component the data to display on toggle.
- **Use** your new component like this

  ````
          <div class="col-sm-5" *ngFor="let atl of TodayAttendance">
              <app-today-attendance [alt]="alt"><app-today-attendance>
          <div>
  <div>```
  ````

You could also simply pass an argument to the expand() method, but you would miss something of the way angular want's you to do stuff.

You should really consider using Angular's components architecture concept, because this is one of it's simplest exmaple.

Comment: Yeah just like poulay said. However I would have more components. Create components for

Comment: Yeah just like poulay said. However I would have more components. Create components for Card, title, description, toggle, collapsible and use input and output to make everything talk to each other. Also your card can do more. <Card class="card col-4" *ngFor="let card of cards" [card]="card"></Card>